# How do you debug opscode chef / ruby errors?

Tags: ruby, debugging, chef-infra

I'm a python guy and struggling to make sense of ruby stacktraces. I'd appreciate if anyone can tell me a systematic method to get to the bottom of what is causing a message like this. Running Opscode 11.4. I thought its probably due to an outdated opscode cookbook, so updated ark to 0.0.17 - the latest. However the problem persists. I thought perhaps it was a dependancy of another cookbook. It is, elasticsearch, however no version is specified. In any case this method seems like guess work however there is not a clear stack trace of where the underlaying problem is. What is the correct way to action such a message?

```
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - users
  - ark
  - elasticsearch
  - openssl
  - sudo
  - yum
  - ohai
  - munin
  - bluepill
  - runit
  - postgresql
  - build-essential
  - apt
  - git
  - nginx
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ark/libraries/resource_ark.rb
================================================================================


NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `attribute' for Chef::Resource::Ark:Class


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ark/libraries/resource_ark.rb:37


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ark/libraries/resource_ark.rb:

 30:          @allowed_actions.push(:install, :dump, :cherry_pick, :put, :install_with_make, :configure, :setup_py_build, :setup_py_install, :setup_py)
 31:          @action = :install
 32:          @provider = Chef::Provider::Ark
 33:        end
 34:  
 35:        attr_accessor :path, :release_file, :prefix_bin, :prefix_root, :home_dir, :extension, :version
 36:  
 37>>       attribute :owner, :kind_of => String, :default => 'root'
 38:        attribute :group, :kind_of => [String, Fixnum], :default => 0
 39:        attribute :url, :kind_of => String, :required => true
 40:        attribute :path, :kind_of => String, :default => nil
 41:        attribute :full_path, :kind_of => String, :default => nil
 42:        attribute :append_env_path, :kind_of => [TrueClass, FalseClass], :default => false
 43:        attribute :checksum, :regex => /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{64}$/, :default => nil
 44:        attribute :has_binaries, :kind_of => Array, :default => []
 45:        attribute :creates, :kind_of => String, :default => nil
 46:        attribute :release_file, :kind_of => String, :default => ''



[2013-02-25T00:19:30+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-02-25T00:19:30+00:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
[2013-02-25T00:19:30+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-02-25T00:19:30+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-02-25T00:19:30+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `attribute' for Chef::Resource::Ark:Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the community site version 0.0.17 is not the same as the current head even though they have the same version number. Installing source from github https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ark/commit/b8c4aaf17d6e88aa857af6b2038eb0dba9981c0b solved the problem.

Comment: We haven't run that through the test suite yet. Once we do, it will be released to the community site w/ a new version.